# How to find and hire technical support generalist?

Tags: hiring, job-description

My company has determined that we need a certain kind of person to fill a role that I'm calling "technical support generalist", but I don't know really what to call it (and thus, how to find such people).

We're a small software company, with two developers (including me), one tester, no real project manager, and no real technical support staff. If anything goes wrong, it falls to us. And that's generally been okay.

But gradually the software has gotten more complex, the user base is growing, and the number of incoming problem reports is enough that we're getting a bit overwhelmed. We can still handle the development work, and even the problems, but we need someone to interface with users and triage the issues so that we deal with them in an orderly way.

But this isn't just "tech support", in the sense of answering the call or email and telling the user what to do, because it's simple and repeated. We need a single person who can receive the message, manage the queue of such messages, triage them, and then do some non-trivial research on the issue before reporting it to the dev team.

For instance, our logins are generally done via SSO, based on an import of known users. So
if someone can't log in, there are maybe a half dozen reasons, having to do with a bad data feed, or missing data, or a bad import of that feed, or a processing glitch, or a network glitch, and so on. What we want is someone who can also be trained in this data pipeline, research the possible reasons for an issue, and file the report with these preliminaries worked out, to save the dev's time.

We also need this person to make judgment calls about what's important, set up a reporting system, and assist development in all sorts of to-be-determined ways. It's a small shop, so that means wearing many hats.

So I guess I mean a technical support person, but with enough actual technical skills to be a part of the resolution team, not just answer the phone. Is that a known position? What is  it called?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You need a skilled devops person. That is a highly specialized role. **not tech-support**. And since you don't seem to realize the significance of this, you need a technical manager above you.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there is no such thing as a "tech support generalist".  The problem is that "tech support" doesn't support the same thing at every company.  The skillset may vary wildly between companies.

What you should to is take stock of the tools, technologies, and business processes that are being supported and come up with two lists:

1. A MUST HAVE set of skills
2. A GOOD TO HAVE set of skills

And start your search using recruiters or job posting sites.

If this were my problem I'd be looking for a candidate that has a good coverage of the "must" list and at least a couple of the "good to have" list.  I'd also be looking for someone with a history of taking on new challenges and learning new things.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're asking for lots of different things.

Firstly, on the support side, this is general split into different tiers or levels or lines. These will vary a bit between organisations, but are something like:

- First line - Initial point of contact for requests, does initial triage and deals with basic issues.
- Second line - Provides more in-depth technical support, and deals with issues that have been escalated to them by the first line.
- Third line - Specialists who deal with complex issues that the second line escalate to them. They will usually be experts in a particular areas (databases, networking, AD, etc).

You'll need to to hire someone that's at least second line to provide the more in-depth troubleshooting that you wan. But that's obviously going to cost more - and if they spend too much of their time answers phone calls and dealing with boring trivial issues, they're going to get fed up and find a more interesting job.

But you also need someone who can build a support function for you (including a ticketing system, internal processes, etc). Doing this well means that they also need to be able to deal with other people at a business level, and to establish things like OLAs and SLAs - which is not necessarily something that technical staff are very good at.

So really you it sounds like you need find a second line support person who's willing to also act as the first line, *and* to build up the support desk function from scratch, including all the administrative and management sides. And they'll also need to be familiar with whatever your stack is, and open to getting involved with your developers. You're asking a lot more than a normal support desk position, so you're going to have to pay more to get it.

---

The other thing that you should considered is whether you *really* need a full time support person given the size of your company. Have you looked at outsourcing your support to a third party IT provider/MSP?

Doing so can provide you with a much deep pool of resources that you can call on, and will meant that you don't have to spend time building the support function from scratch. It also means that you've got cover when your support person is on holiday/sick/etc, and avoids the risk that you spend a while training them up and then they quit.

Answer (score 0):

First, hire a SW project manager. Task the project manager with these items for the first six months or so with the promise that the project manager will hire someone by then. The PM will manage the hiring process for that.

You'll probably benefit from having a PM given your growing complexity, and some of the tasks you describe fit a PM: tracking issues, setting up a reporting system, assisting in development, etc. The others would still help the PM get integrated into your project.

Comment: This is good advice. I'm not sure I can sell it to management, but we do need a PM as well, and there's probably a lot of overlap in the tasks.

Comment: Tech support is an operations role, not a projects role. :(

Comment: @XavierJ: I think that's right, but there is some overlap, especially in a small company with the budget for just one person.